# Insert missing datetime rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
            is_avail   valu data_source
2015-08-07     False  0.282    source_a
2015-08-23     False  0.296    source_a
2015-09-08     False  0.433    source_a
2015-10-01      True  0.169    source_a
2015-10-10      True  0.160    source_a
2015-11-02     False  0.179    source_a
2016-03-09     False  0.557    source_a
2016-04-26     False  0.770    source_a
2016-05-05     False  0.826    source_a
2016-05-12     False  0.826    source_a
2016-05-28     False  0.747    source_a
2016-06-06     False  0.796    source_a
2016-07-31     False  0.322    source_a
2016-08-25      True  0.136    source_a
2016-09-10     False  0.180    source_a
2016-11-13     False  0.492    source_a
2016-12-15      True  0.124    source_a
2016-12-31     False  0.533    source_a
2017-03-28     False  0.524    source_a
2015-06-27      True  0.038    source_b
2015-07-30      True  0.035    source_b
2015-08-06     False  0.205    source_b
2015-08-09     False  0.241    source_b
2015-08-16      True  0.025    source_b
2015-08-19      True  0.092    source_b
2015-08-26     False  0.264    source_b
2015-08-29     False  0.312    source_b
```

The above dataframe has an index of datetime objects. I want to add rows for dates which are currently missing in the dataframe. However, I want to add those rows separately for `source_a` and `source_b`. E.g. `2015-08-08` is a missing date for both `source_a` and `source_b` so I want to add that in the dataframe for both of them. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you want to fill the missing rows with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `resample` in a `groupby` and `ffill` (forward fill)

```
df.groupby(
    'data_source', group_keys=False
).apply(lambda df: df.resample('D').ffill())
```

Or you can `interpolate` for `valu` and `ffill` the rest.

```
df.groupby(
    'data_source', group_keys=False
).apply(
    lambda df: df.resample('D').interpolate('index').ffill()
)
```